# Python.Tkinter. Как назначить команду на кнопку в цикле, считывая данные из json-файла?

Tags: python, json, tkinter

В цикле считывается файл `settings.json` с категориями. Создаются окна, количество которых равно количеству словарей массива.

Во внутреннем цикле создаются кнопки. Причём, в каждом окне кнопкам задаётся определённое имя из словаря.

Проблема заключается в том, что в `bind` посылается лишь последнее имя команды - `thunar`. То есть, все кнопки вызывают `thunar`.

Как это исправить?

*Программа*:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-#
from tkinter import *
import json

for category in json.load(open('settings.json')):
    topwindow = Toplevel()
    stuff = []

    for apps in category['apps']:
        stuff.append(apps['command'])

        button1 = Button(topwindow,text=apps['name'])
        button1.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e: print(apps['command']))
        button1.pack(fill='both')

        print("name: {0} command: {1}".format(apps['name'],apps['command']))


topwindow.mainloop()
```

*settings.json*:

```
    [
    {
        "name": "Офис",
        "icon-name": "applications-office",
        "icon-size": "18", 
        "apps":  [{
                "name": "Libreoffice Writer",
                "command": "libreoffice --writer"
            },
            {
                "name": "Libreoffice Calc",
                "command": "libreoffice --calc"
            },
            {
                "name":"Libreoffice Impress",
                "command":"Libreoffice --impress"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "name": "Программирование",
        "icon-name": "applications-development",
        "icon-size": "18", 
        "apps":  [{
            "name": "Sublime Text",
            "command": "subl"
            },
            {
            "name": "Code::Blocs",
            "command": "codeblocks"
            }
        ]
     },

    {
        "name": "Видео Аудио",
        "icon-name": "applications-multimedia",
        "icon-size": "18", 
        "apps":  [{
            "name": "VLC медиаплеер",
            "command": "vlc"
            },
            {
            "name": "Audacity",
            "command": "audacity"
            }
        ]},

    {
        "name": "Интернет",
        "icon-name": "applications-internet",
        "icon-size": "18", 
        "apps":  [{
            "name": "Интернет браузер",
            "command": "firefox"
            },
            {
            "name": "Консольный интернет браузер",
            "command": "lynx"
            }
        ]},

    {
        "name": "Система",
        "icon-name": "preferences-system",
        "icon-size": "18", 
        "apps":  [{
            "name": "XTerm",
            "command": "xterm"
            },
            {
            "name": "Настройки \"WP Desktop\"",
            "command": "wpsettings_gui --root"
            }
        ]
     },

    {
        "name": "Пользователь",
        "icon-name": "user-home",
        "icon-size": "18", 
        "apps":  [{
            "name": "Файловый менеджер",
            "command": "thunar"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Why results of map() and list comprehension are different?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/139819/4279)

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде callback-функция всегда обращалась к переменной `apps`, которая имела значение, присвоенное в **последней итерации** цикла, это и вызывало всегда одно и тоже значение. Для решения задачи можно использовать значение аргумента функции по умолчанию.

Также нет смысла создавать ссылку на объект кнопки, которая будет перезаписана при каждой итерации.

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-#
from tkinter import *
import json

Tk().withdraw() # блокируем отрисовку главного окна

for category in json.load(open('settings.json')):
    topwindow = Toplevel()
    stuff = []

    for apps in category['apps']:
        stuff.append(apps['command'])

        cmd = lambda e=apps['command']: print(e) # задаем значение аргумента по умолчанию 
        Button(topwindow, text=apps['name'], command=cmd).pack(fill='both')

       print("name: {0} command: {1}".format(apps['name'],apps['command']))


topwindow.mainloop()
```